# Oracle SQL Migrate Data Optimization

Tags: sql, oracle

I have three tables UserTable,UserTablebBackUp and UserBlackList. Each table has approximately 35M data.

I want to migrate each tupple from UserTable to UserTablebBackUp ,where entiry is not in UserBlackList. Created a script as following. Do you have a way of optimizing this script? Otherwise It is the best one? Thanks.

```
insert /*+APPEND+*/ INTO UserTablebBackUp (id_backup) select id from UserTable 
        where id not IN (SELECT id from UserBlackList);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insert /*+APPEND+*/ INTO UserTablebBackUp(id_backup) select a.id from usertable a
left outer join userblacklist b on a.id=b.id where b.id is null
```

it should be faster...

Comment: Yes, the left join should help.  If you want to migrate more columns than just the id, you'll need something like `INSERT INTO UserTableBackUp (id_backup, col2, col3, col4) SELECT id, col2, col3, col4 FROM UserTable a LEFT JOIN UserBlackList b ON b.id = a.id WHERE b.id IS NULL`

Comment: This is unlikely to make any difference.  Oracle can automatically perform this optimization through [subquery unnesting](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e15858/tgsql_transform.htm#BABEIDIA).

Comment: A left join is not necessarily equivalent to an `in` query. Depending on the data it might produce a different result set.

Answer (score 0):

**Parallelism**  With 35M rows you can probably benefit from [parallel execution](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/parallel001.htm#CACEEBJJ).
There are a lot of requirements though, such as Enterprise Edition, parallel settings, a sane hardware configuration, sufficient resources, etc.

If you're using 11gR2, it might be as simple as this:

```
insert /*+ APPEND PARALLEL*/
INTO UserTablebBackUp (id_backup) select id from UserTable 
where id not IN (SELECT id from UserBlackList);
```

**Direct-Path Writes** You are probably already getting this, but it's worth double-checking.
The APPEND hint alone is not always sufficient, there are lots of restrictions on direct-path writes.
If you are using a direct-path insert you should see `LOAD AS SELECT` in your execution plan, instead of `LOAD TABLE CONVENTIONAL`.
If you are still getting conventional inserts, see the [SQL Language Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9014.htm#SQLRF55049) for some restrictions, as well as
[this useful matrix](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:5280714813869) of nologging settings.

Even for such a simple query you should always post the explain plan.